# How to execute Cygwin commands from LabView

Tags: bash, makefile, cygwin, labview, mintty

Normally, I manually execute some Cygwin commands to run a `Makefile`. It is just a chain of 2 commands:

```
$ cd 'path\to\my\folder'
$ make
```

I would like to automatize this task by running a `labview` program that does this for me, but i do not know how to do it.

I have checked this web: http://www.labvolution.com/executing-perl-scripts-labview/.

In that tutorial, the guy runs a cygwin command from LabView with the System Terminal Exec `vi`, and with this command, he executes a program. However, in my case, it does not work, since I just don't see anything happening. Furthermore, in my case, i need two successive commands (`cd` and then `make`), not just one.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

what about

```
command1 && command2
```

or

```
command1; command2
```